# Adding in missing months to a dataframe with null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that I am trying to find the frequency of certain events with. So for example, it is listed as follows

```
Month Year Event UniqueID
1     2018 A     01
1     2018 A     02
2     2018 B     03
....
```

etc. I have everything grouped by frequency of Event per year. I did that by using the following code.

This counts up all the events so I can average them

```
df.groupby(['Year','Month','Event'])['Event'].size().rename('Count of Events').reset_index()
```

Which gives us something along the lines of

```
Year Month Event Count of Events
2018 01    A     2
2018 02    B     1
...
```

And then I'm getting the average of how often it happens a month for the entire year by using

```
df.groupby(['Event'])['Count of Events'].mean()
```

Which gives me the average. However one thing I noticed is that I may have gaps. For example event 'A', may occur in Jan and Feb, but not March, so this won't give me a true "average" over the year. What would be the best way to "Plug up" These holes? For example, in the above example list,

```
Month Year Event Count of Events
1     2018 A     02
1     2018 B     00
1     2018 C     00
2     2018 A     00
2     2018 B     00
2     2018 B     01
...
```

Would be the optimal final outcome before I average it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close to the solution. After grouping, unstack the dataframe to a "wide" form (that way you will have every combination of a month and a year), fill the missing values with 0s, and stack it back:

```
df.groupby(["Month", "Year", "Event"]).size().unstack().fillna(0).stack()
#Month  Year  Event
#1      2018  A        2.0
#             B        0.0
#2      2018  A        0.0
#             B        1.0
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Is there an easy way to keep the 4th column (The "derived" count of column named this way without using .rename?

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by *DYZ* produces data only for "present" months.

But consider source data like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ 1, 2018, 'A', '01' ], [ 1, 2018, 'A', '02' ], [ 2, 2018, 'B', '03' ],
    [ 4, 2018, 'A', '04' ], [ 4, 2018, 'A', '05' ], [ 7, 2018, 'A', '06' ],
    [ 7, 2018, 'B', '07' ], [ 7, 2018, 'B', '08' ] ],
    columns=['Month', 'Year', 'Event', 'UniqueID'])
```

where there are no data for March, May and June, so the result printed according to
*DYZ* will have "gaps".

Note also such a detail concerning "gaps" is source data:

- For some event type you can have "absent" data also for **first** and/or
  **last** month.
- But nevertheless, at least in my opinion, the **true** mean should be computed
  as a sum of events of particular type, divided by the number of months of
  **the whole activity**, not by the span of months of the **current** activity.

E.g. in my data sample, if the first event was in January and the last in July,
**regardless of the event type**, then the whole activity took **7** months.

So one of steps should be to compute `MonthNo` - the number of months of the
**whole** activity.

Another proposition is to "switch" from separate *Year* / *Month* columns to *Dat*
(DateTime) and set it as the index. This column (actually index) will be needed
at some point (see below).

So my proposition how to write the script is:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

# Source data
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[ [ 1, 2018, 'A', '01' ], [ 1, 2018, 'A', '02' ],
    [ 2, 2018, 'B', '03' ], [ 4, 2018, 'A', '04' ], [ 4, 2018, 'A', '05' ],
    [ 7, 2018, 'A', '06' ], [ 7, 2018, 'B', '07' ], [ 7, 2018, 'B', '08' ] ],
    columns=['Month', 'Year', 'Event', 'UniqueID'])
# Count of Events
df2 = df.groupby(['Year','Month','Event'])['Event'].size()\
    .rename('Count of Events').reset_index()
# Replace Year / Month with Dat
df2['Dat'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.Year * 10000 + df2.Month * 100 + 1,
    format='%Y%m%d')
df2.drop(columns=['Year', 'Month'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index('Dat', inplace=True)
# How many months took the activity
MonthNo = math.ceil((df2.index.max() - df2.index.min())/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')) + 1
```

Then, if you want to have rows with zero count of events for "gap" months, call
`resample` for each event type (here the DateTime index is needed):

```
df3 = df2.groupby(['Event']).resample('MS').sum()
```

The result is:

```
                  Count of Events
Event Dat                        
A     2018-01-01                2
      2018-02-01                0
      2018-03-01                0
      2018-04-01                2
      2018-05-01                0
      2018-06-01                0
      2018-07-01                1
B     2018-02-01                1
      2018-03-01                0
      2018-04-01                0
      2018-05-01                0
      2018-06-01                0
      2018-07-01                2
```

And to compute the mean number of events of each type, per month of the
**whole activity**, call:

```
df3.groupby(level=0).sum() / MonthNo
```

getting:

```
       Count of Events
Event                 
A             0.714286
B             0.428571
```

Note that *resample* was neede only to get months without gaps,
not to computer the mean numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is fillna: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

It's a really easy way to fill null values and designate what to fill them with.

Comment: I think the issue is that some combinations of the `groupby` columns (`Year, Month`) simply don't appear in the original DataFrame, so the resulting DataFrame is missing entire rows -- there are no `np.nan` values to fill at all.